# Adding row numbers Windows phone 7 listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a problem and I have no idea what to do. I am trying to make a simple highscore list and I need to get numbers (1,2,3,4...) for each score.

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source.View}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ROW_NUMBER_HERE}"/>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}"/>
                              </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
public System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource Source { get; set; }

        public HighscorePage()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            if (store.FileExists("highscores"))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("highscores", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>));
                        Items = (ObservableCollection<Item>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                }
            }
            if (Items != null)
            {
                Source = new System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource();
                Source.Source = Items;
                Source.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Score", ListSortDirection.Descending));
            }

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
      }
```

That Items ObservableCollection contains Name and Score data.

I tried to use normal while loop to add numbers without success. And I couldn't get AlternationCount to work either. Is it even supported in wp7? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Select extension to do the counting and a new class to be bound to, this can be done by creating an alternate list with the rownumbers. Here is how:

Create an extended Items Class (ItemsEx) which has one extra property which is an `int` for `RowNumber` property. Also have a copy constructor which takes an `Item` and copies the valid info into the clone.

Have the observable collection of ItemsEx(s) and store the old (if needed in a list):

```
public List<Item> Items { get; set; }                       // Original
public ObservableCollection<ItemEx> Items2 { get; set; }    // Changed to hold the RowNumber
```

When you have the items from the isolated storage create your ItemsEx instances such as

```
    var itemsToBePlaceInCollection 
        = Items.Select((itm, index) => new ItemEx(itm) { RowNumber = index + 1; })
               .ToList();
               .ForEach(itmEx => Items2.Add( itmEx ));   // Add into the observable collection at this point
```

Then in the Xaml, DataContext is set to Items2 and the template binds to `RowNumber` off of ItemEx which will reflect the count from storage and you get your row numbers shown.

---

Frankly its unclear why you need an `ObservableCollection` if the list is not being added to dynamically. If it is not, then simply creating a new list on the fly with an INotifyPropertyChanged would be just as effective instead of having an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I like this idea to make a new list with numbers but in my case I am not sure if I'm able to do so. 

Well I am using observableCollection because I need to sort list by scores and after that I need to add those "row numbers". 
And in fact I am using this same file/list in two different listboxes, sorted by player level(easy,normal). Another listbox include "easy" level scores and another "normal" level scores. But let's keep this simple :)

Maybe I could open data, sort and filtered it and after that put it with row numbers in two different lists. I will try! Thanks!

Comment: @Arnoho if nothing else using an extended class for your data which speaks to the differing needs of the view is a good place to start.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean?
<br/><br/>
Simplest way to solve my problem would be add numbers 1,2,3,4,5...,n for each LISTBOX item, not my data item.
<br/>
Data items are sorted by player score and when loading highscore page they move to listbox. That's why this number need to give it when system loads listbox items to xaml. 
<br/>
I don't really know how to explain this but I don't need to save this number into data.Only purpose is show it in listbox.
<br/>
So list would look like:<br/>
1. player  200p<br/>
2. player2  10p<br/>
3. player3  0p<br/>
... and so on.

Comment: @Arnoho the extended class (based off of the original) will hold that *temporary* number and simply allow the UI to display that number as needed. There will be no *persisting* that value or use of the extended class after that. The class is only there to facility this (or possibly) other situations where extended data not a part of the original data is needed.